# knockout js datapicker options

Tags: date, knockout.js

using this code

```
                        <input type="text"
                         id="StudentDOB"
                         class="controls span2"
                         data-bind="datepicker: StudentDOB"
                         name="StudentDOB" />
```

yeilds the following result.

[image]

When I change the code to

```
          <input type="text"
                 id="StudentDOB"
                 class="controls span2"
                 data-bind="datepicker: StudentDOB, datepickerOptions: {}"
                 name="StudentDOB" />
```

It appears as follows: 
[image]

Now I want the year and month option while setting my max year to 2014. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date picker you are talking about is not the the knockout datepicker as there is no such thing. It's the jQueryUI datepicker. The options are in the api documentation on the jQueryUI website: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
datepickerOptions: { changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, yearRange: '1900:2014' }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4kkg/

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: This looks like it might work. Can you point me to the documentation for this?

Comment: how dumb of me! I had been searching for the datepicker bits in the knockout documentation and it just slipped my mind that it was jqueryUi. Thanks for the answer!